# Fragment generic view model in dagger 2

Tags: android, viewmodel, dagger-2

I am trying to make a CustomBaseFragment that receives a base View Model and then initializes it and performs the providers based on the view model that is being passed in raw.
I also created a TestFragment that inherits the CustomBaseFragment and passes a View Model TestViewModel.
Something like this:

Custom Base Fragment:

```
 public class CustomBaseFragment<V extends BaseViewModel> extends DaggerFragment
{
    public V viewModel;
    @Inject
    ViewModelProviderFactory providerFactory;

    void initViewModel()
    {
        viewModel = (V) ViewModelProviders.of(this, providerFactory).get(viewModel.getClass());
    }
}
```

BaseViewModel:

```
public class BaseViewModel extends ViewModel
{
    @Inject

    public BaseViewModel()
    {
        
    }
}
```

TestFragment:

```
    public class TestFragment extends CustomBaseFragment<TestViewModel>
{

}
```

TestViewModel:

```
      public class TestViewModel extends BaseViewModel
{
    @Inject
    public TestViewModel()
    {
    }
}
```

Apparently in code everything is fine, but the dagger is complaining about some things that I don't know how to solve :(
The error follows:

```
Cannot inject members into raw type oficial.com.v2.ui.CustomBaseFragment    
.di.FragmentBuildersModule_ContributeCustom.CustomBaseFragmentSubcomponent.Factory does not implement AndroidInjector <oficial.com.v2.ui.CustomBaseFragment <V>>
       @ClassKey (CustomBaseFragment.class)
       ^
```

My FragmentBuildersModule:

```
 @ContributesAndroidInjector()
abstract CustomBaseFragment contributeCustom();
```

if I try:

```
 @ContributesAndroidInjector()
    abstract CustomBaseFragment<BaseViewModel> contributeCustom();
```

I get

```
error: @ContributesAndroidInjector methods cannot return parameterized types
```

Does anyone have an idea how to solve?

Comment: At some point you have to provide the concrete type to dagger otherwise it won't know what its injecting into and what objects it needs. The error message is saying exactly that .. A parameterized type can be any number of sub types that fit the generics ..

Comment: provide base view model?

Comment: Concrete fragment - you want to inject it and provide its dependencies

Comment: thanks! really works!